# How is the ulimit -c unlimited command used and what does it do?

Tags: c, netbeans, coredump, ulimit

I'm helping to write a program right now, and on windows, the program works fine. On the mac, after changing the framework directory to the only suitable location, I'm getting this error:

`run:`

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff92309bb2, pid=12438, tid=44807

JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [CoreFoundation+0x1bb2]  CFDictionaryGetValue+0x12

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/Downloads/BiscuitAnimator-Mac-master/hs_err_pid12438.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Java Result: 134
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

How do I use the ulimit -c unlimited command/set up core dumping in NetBeans?

Comment: You can close the Netbeans completely, then go to console, do the `ulimit -c unlimited` command and then start netbeans from console. Ulimit settings is derived when you start program from the console shell.

Comment: There may be some setting you can look up to set default resource limits for processes launched by the GUI, too.

Comment: Go to console or terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some bug (unexpected error scenarios) in your program and it is resulting in crashing your program, you should be able to debug why the program has crashed. 
For this purpose the Operating system will copy process stack into a file called core dump file.

ulimit , is a system command.

ulimit -c unlimited, command used to set the core dump file size to unlimited.
Instead of unlimited you can specify the maximum limit of the core dump file size also.

for more information type 
man ulimit

Comment: That is really helpful, the man ulimit command, but how would I implement that into my code, because I've tried this:

`public static void main(String args[ulimit -c unlimited]) throws InterruptedException`